# How do I make a XSLT to format this exported xml in a table format?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to stack exchange so I apologise in advance for any mistakes I might make ...
I have this xml exported from our image management software and I would like to format it in a table format. The export allows the use of XSL to format the data, but offers no examples of how to do it.
I'm hoping this will be a fairly simple task once given some pointers.
Thanks in advance ...
Jeremy

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Export>
<ns:Export xmlns:ns="http://www.canto.com/ns/Export/1.0">
<ns:Layout tableName="AssetRecords">
    <ns:Fields>
        <ns:Field uid="{af4b2e00-5f6a-11d2-8f20-0000c0e166dc}" type="0" valueInterpretation="0">
            <ns:Name>Record Name</ns:Name>
        </ns:Field>
        <ns:Field uid="{af4b2e43-5f6a-11d2-8f20-0000c0e166dc}" type="0" valueInterpretation="0">
            <ns:Name>Title</ns:Name>
        </ns:Field>
        <ns:Field uid="{0ab76098-1c48-11d5-acb3-00306510d9c9}" type="0" valueInterpretation="0">
            <ns:Name>Accession Number</ns:Name>
        </ns:Field>
        <ns:Field uid="{9aac53db-e086-4d3d-8016-299f73df292e}" type="0" valueInterpretation="0">
            <ns:Name>Artist</ns:Name>
        </ns:Field>
        <ns:Field uid="{3248196a-a576-11d5-8c20-003065ed2114}" type="0" valueInterpretation="0">
            <ns:Name>Vernon</ns:Name>
        </ns:Field>
    </ns:Fields>
</ns:Layout>
<ns:Items>
    <ns:Item catalogid="3" id="320361">
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{af4b2e00-5f6a-11d2-8f20-0000c0e166dc}">Ca102450.tif</ns:FieldValue>
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{af4b2e43-5f6a-11d2-8f20-0000c0e166dc}">Plant forms pendant</ns:FieldValue>
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{0ab76098-1c48-11d5-acb3-00306510d9c9}">2013.133</ns:FieldValue>
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{9aac53db-e086-4d3d-8016-299f73df292e}">INDIAN</ns:FieldValue>
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{3248196a-a576-11d5-8c20-003065ed2114}">109996</ns:FieldValue>
    </ns:Item>
    <ns:Item catalogid="3" id="320587">
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{af4b2e00-5f6a-11d2-8f20-0000c0e166dc}">Ca102453.tif</ns:FieldValue>
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{af4b2e43-5f6a-11d2-8f20-0000c0e166dc}">Horse and rider pendant</ns:FieldValue>
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{0ab76098-1c48-11d5-acb3-00306510d9c9}">2013.212</ns:FieldValue>
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{9aac53db-e086-4d3d-8016-299f73df292e}">INDIAN</ns:FieldValue>
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{3248196a-a576-11d5-8c20-003065ed2114}">110102</ns:FieldValue>
    </ns:Item>
    <ns:Item catalogid="3" id="320612">
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{af4b2e00-5f6a-11d2-8f20-0000c0e166dc}">Ca102455.tif</ns:FieldValue>
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{af4b2e43-5f6a-11d2-8f20-0000c0e166dc}">Durga pendant</ns:FieldValue>
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{0ab76098-1c48-11d5-acb3-00306510d9c9}">2013.238</ns:FieldValue>
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{9aac53db-e086-4d3d-8016-299f73df292e}">INDIAN</ns:FieldValue>
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{3248196a-a576-11d5-8c20-003065ed2114}">110129</ns:FieldValue>
    </ns:Item>
    <ns:Item catalogid="3" id="320596">
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{af4b2e00-5f6a-11d2-8f20-0000c0e166dc}">Ca102458.tif</ns:FieldValue>
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{af4b2e43-5f6a-11d2-8f20-0000c0e166dc}">Horse and rider mould</ns:FieldValue>
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{0ab76098-1c48-11d5-acb3-00306510d9c9}">2013.221</ns:FieldValue>
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{9aac53db-e086-4d3d-8016-299f73df292e}">INDIAN</ns:FieldValue>
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{3248196a-a576-11d5-8c20-003065ed2114}">110113</ns:FieldValue>
    </ns:Item>
    <ns:Item catalogid="3" id="320610">
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{af4b2e00-5f6a-11d2-8f20-0000c0e166dc}">Ca102461.tif</ns:FieldValue>
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{af4b2e43-5f6a-11d2-8f20-0000c0e166dc}">Durga mould</ns:FieldValue>
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{0ab76098-1c48-11d5-acb3-00306510d9c9}">2013.236</ns:FieldValue>
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{9aac53db-e086-4d3d-8016-299f73df292e}">INDIAN</ns:FieldValue>
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{3248196a-a576-11d5-8c20-003065ed2114}">110127</ns:FieldValue>
    </ns:Item>
    <ns:Item catalogid="3" id="320622">
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{af4b2e00-5f6a-11d2-8f20-0000c0e166dc}">Ca102463.tif</ns:FieldValue>
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{af4b2e43-5f6a-11d2-8f20-0000c0e166dc}">Surya pendant</ns:FieldValue>
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{0ab76098-1c48-11d5-acb3-00306510d9c9}">2013.248</ns:FieldValue>
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{9aac53db-e086-4d3d-8016-299f73df292e}">INDIAN</ns:FieldValue>
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{3248196a-a576-11d5-8c20-003065ed2114}">110140</ns:FieldValue>
    </ns:Item>
    <ns:Item catalogid="3" id="320492">
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{af4b2e00-5f6a-11d2-8f20-0000c0e166dc}">Ca102466.tif</ns:FieldValue>
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{af4b2e43-5f6a-11d2-8f20-0000c0e166dc}">Ganesh mould</ns:FieldValue>
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{0ab76098-1c48-11d5-acb3-00306510d9c9}">2013.117</ns:FieldValue>
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{9aac53db-e086-4d3d-8016-299f73df292e}">INDIAN</ns:FieldValue>
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{3248196a-a576-11d5-8c20-003065ed2114}">109980</ns:FieldValue>
    </ns:Item>
    <ns:Item catalogid="3" id="320623">
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{af4b2e00-5f6a-11d2-8f20-0000c0e166dc}">Ca102468.tif</ns:FieldValue>
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{af4b2e43-5f6a-11d2-8f20-0000c0e166dc}">Figure mould</ns:FieldValue>
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{0ab76098-1c48-11d5-acb3-00306510d9c9}">2013.249</ns:FieldValue>
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{9aac53db-e086-4d3d-8016-299f73df292e}">INDIAN</ns:FieldValue>
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{3248196a-a576-11d5-8c20-003065ed2114}">110141</ns:FieldValue>
    </ns:Item>
    <ns:Item catalogid="3" id="320458">
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{af4b2e00-5f6a-11d2-8f20-0000c0e166dc}">Ca102470.tif</ns:FieldValue>
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{af4b2e43-5f6a-11d2-8f20-0000c0e166dc}">Shiva and Parvati on horseback mould</ns:FieldValue>
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{0ab76098-1c48-11d5-acb3-00306510d9c9}">2013.231</ns:FieldValue>
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{9aac53db-e086-4d3d-8016-299f73df292e}">INDIAN</ns:FieldValue>
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{3248196a-a576-11d5-8c20-003065ed2114}">110122</ns:FieldValue>
    </ns:Item>
    <ns:Item catalogid="3" id="320366">
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{af4b2e00-5f6a-11d2-8f20-0000c0e166dc}">Ca102474.tif</ns:FieldValue>
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{af4b2e43-5f6a-11d2-8f20-0000c0e166dc}">Hanuman mould</ns:FieldValue>
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{0ab76098-1c48-11d5-acb3-00306510d9c9}">2013.138</ns:FieldValue>
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{9aac53db-e086-4d3d-8016-299f73df292e}">INDIAN</ns:FieldValue>
        <ns:FieldValue uid="{3248196a-a576-11d5-8c20-003065ed2114}">110001</ns:FieldValue>
    </ns:Item>
</ns:Items>
</ns:Export>
```

I'd like the data formatted in rows ...

```
Record Name  Title                   Accession Number    Artist    Vernon
Ca102450     Plant forms pendant     2013.133            Indian    109996
Ca102453     Horse and rider pendant 2013.212            Indian    110102
etc
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be a generic transform, or one for that specific case? If it's generic, how would it know to remove the .tif from the Record Name values and change all except the first letter of the Artist values to lowercase?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to have a look ...

Comment: You're welcome. Are you going to answer my question? Also, why do two of the fields have the same UID?

Comment: Sorry to keep you waiting. I hand typed the output table, left off the .tif and canged the case of the Artist values by mistake.

Comment: not sure about the uid, this is a coy paste direct from the xml output file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, Welcome to stack overflow, where we can really explore, share many ideas and solve our problems.

When you transform the below XSLT with your XML you will get the table format

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns="http://www.canto.com/ns/Export/1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="ns">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="ns:Export"><table xmlns:ns="http://www.canto.com/ns/Export/1.0"><xsl:apply-templates/></table></xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="ns:Fields"><thead><tr><xsl:apply-templates/></tr></thead></xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="ns:Field/ns:Name"><td><xsl:apply-templates/></td></xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="ns:Items"><tbody><xsl:apply-templates/></tbody></xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="ns:Item"><tr><xsl:apply-templates/></tr></xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="ns:FieldValue"><td><xsl:apply-templates/></td></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That first version was just what i meant! I don't want to alter the data on the way out. I hand typed that table to give the idea of what the table should look like, and made a few changes to the data by mistake,

Comment: @jeremy As per your request find the previous version which I done, If It was correct, then make it as correct answer